# Drupal 8 and civicrm version compatability

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-multi-site

I am trying to get CiviCRM working against Drupal 8.

For testing and setting up I am currently using:

- Oracle VBox 6
- UBuntu 18.04
- php 7.2.17
- mysql 5.7.26
- composer 1.8.5

Let me know if there is anything else relevant or if the above combination does not work.

I am trying to follow  David Snopek's  latest how to 
https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/better-way-install-civicrm-drupal-8

In it David gives the following example:

> composer create-project roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project:8.x-dev some-dir –no-interaction

As I am aiming for something as stable as possible while still on the bleeding edge. (I know that is a contradiction)

I used the following in the  /var/www/html

> composer create-project drupal/drupal  /var/www/html/drupal

I then went in via my browser and set up Drupal 8  with a standard install. 
I did not add any modules etc. 
So now I have Drupal 8.7.0

I then used the following composercommand while in the /var/www/html/drupal directory.
see screen output below:

```
peter@UbuntuVM:/var/www/html$ cd drupal
peter@UbuntuVM:/var/www/html/drupal$ composer require roundearth/civicrm-composer-plugin civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8
Using version dev-master for roundearth/civicrm-composer-plugin
Using version dev-master for civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.9.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.9.1 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.9.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.8.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.8.2 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.8.1 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.8.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.7.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.7.3 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.7.2 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.7.1 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.7.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.6.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.6.1 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.6.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.5.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.5.3 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.5.2 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.5.1 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.5.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.4.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.4.1 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.4.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.12.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.12.4 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.12.3 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.12.2 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.12.1 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.12.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.11.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.11.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.10.x-dev requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.10.4 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.10.3 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.10.2 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.10.1 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.10.0 requires zetacomponents/mail dev-1.7-civi -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 dev-master -> satisfiable by civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: remove psr/log 1.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install psr/log 1.0.2
    - civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 dev-master requires civicrm/civicrm-core >=5.4.0 -> satisfiable by civicrm/civicrm-core[5.10.0, 5.10.1, 5.10.2, 5.10.3, 5.10.4, 5.10.x-dev, 5.11.0, 5.11.x-dev, 5.12.0, 5.12.1, 5.12.2, 5.12.3, 5.12.4, 5.12.x-dev, 5.13.0, 5.13.1, 5.13.2, 5.13.3, 5.13.4, 5.13.x-dev, 5.14.x-dev, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.0, 5.8.1, 5.8.2, 5.8.x-dev, 5.9.0, 5.9.1, 5.9.x-dev, dev-master].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.13.0 requires psr/log ~1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.13.1 requires psr/log ~1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.13.2 requires psr/log ~1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.13.3 requires psr/log ~1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.13.4 requires psr/log ~1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.13.x-dev requires psr/log ~1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.14.x-dev requires psr/log ~1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core dev-master requires psr/log ~1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: psr/log[1.1.0, 1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: psr/log[1.1.x-dev, 1.0.2].
    - Installation request for psr/log (locked at 1.0.2) -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.0.2].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
peter@UbuntuVM:/var/www/html/drupal$
```

I know its a lot but any ideas on how to make this work with a standard drupal 8?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the version of civi you want if it can't figure it out, so e.g.

`composer require roundearth/civicrm-composer-plugin civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 civicrm/civicrm-core:5.13.4`

You might also have to add and specify the psr/log version on the same line to match, based on the error message above.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will be trying some combinations to see what works.